# What if cmd cannot display some characters?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd

If Im using c# I like to display my output on the console. Thats fine, but sometimes cmd is not able to show some characters. Like '**€**' , I only get '**?**' and thats not an encoding problem in my c# code, cmd is just not able to display '**€**' - so how to solve this problem? I could create a .txt with my outputs, yes that could work. Do I have another options? Can I use the powershell 2.0 console for outputs, but how? Or got PS the same problems? Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the font you're using in the console. For example, open a command prompt and try to paste in the € character and you'll see a question mark. But if you right-click the border of the console window and choose Properties > Font, then pick Consolas or Lucida Console, your character will display properly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using a console you can always use a simple winforms app with a RichTextBox control for output. This would even allow you to format output if you felt the need. If you keep it to a single form for output it wouldn't be any more complex than a console app. Instead of `Console.WriteLine` you'd have `rtbOutput.Text +=`.